# mySQL Database Design for a Mutli-User Shopping List Application

Tags: mysql

I am currently in the planning phases of developing a multi-user shopping list application for mobile devices. In a nutshell, it will allow a registered user to create shopping list categories and then add individual items to one of these categories. The users' sets of categories and the items underneath will make up their "list." The user will be able to share their list other authorized users. All these users and the list creator will be able to edit/update these lists.

I'm not very familiar with database design although I feel relatively comfortable with mySQL and its syntax from limited use in past projects and web development. From the tutorials I've read, it is important to minimize redundant data, and in order to do so, and also leverage some of the power of relational database systems, I must use foreign keys and reference table(s).

This is what I've got so far, but now I'm stuck:

[image: DB Diagram]

Essentially my main question is the "list" table done correctly? The way I am seeing this work is that as a user attempts to add an "item", we first to make sure some other user hasn't already created an "item" with the same name; this is to prevent duplicate item text from being stored in the database. If that item name already exists, just toss back the item_id to client program. The same process should occur when a user attempts to create a category. This idea came from my (very) basic understanding of trying to eliminate duplicate objects. If either of these objects don't exist, then they get created in their respective tables.

So now I would add the information to the actual list table. The user_id references which user owns the list, category_id points to a category in the category table and item_id points to an item in the item table. "checked" simply represents whether the item has been checked off the list, but not yet removed.

Is this a tenable design, or should I just start over from scratch? If so, can someone give me some clues as to a better design?